# Confusion with Creating a Class library in C++, VS 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I am working on a 3d game engine which requires some maths, but i want to modulate my code better by putting the math into a library. Right now im using a header file called "DataTypes.hpp" which has all structures and datatypes my engine needs. This also includes my math files, "VMMath.hpp" (this serves as a wrapper) and within here i include four other header files for my vector, matrix and quaternion classes.

My approach being i want DataTypes to be become a precompiled header, and the VMMath code to be a library (static or dll, ill be honest im not sure which). As then i dont have to put the DataType header in all the VMMath sources, and reduce the relevant source files for the project.

From what i have seen a library must be one header and source, which uses extern or static keywords so the header can use the methods in the source. The example on MSDN shows a class in a namespace with no constructors/destructors with static methods. But i find it abit short to really show you what its capable of.

So is it possible to create a library from this sort of file structure:

<-Project Dir->

- (other sources/folders)
- VMMath

  -- VMMath.hpp

  - Math

    -- CVector2.hpp

    -- CVector2.cpp

    -- CPoint2.hpp

    -- CVector3.hpp

    -- CVector3.cpp

    -- CPoint3.hpp

    -- CVector4.hpp

    -- CVector4.cpp

    -- CMatrix3.hpp

    -- CMatrix3.cpp

    -- CMatrix4.hpp

    -- CMatrix4.cpp

    -- CQuaternion.hpp

    -- CQuaternion.cpp

I hope that makes sense. So one way i can see this working is having VMMath.hpp have ALL classes inside, and VMMath.cpp containing ALL the classes source, but this isnt very maintainable. Or would i have to make each class as a seperate dll?

Here is an article from codeproject i have read but it doesn't show a dll with multiple files : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6351/Regular-DLL-Tutor-For-Beginners

I hope ive made my self clear, appologies if i have generated too much reading.

Comment: Please clarify: do you intend to export from the DLL plain C functions or classes?

Comment: Classes and then use the classes methods. Why is using the 'C' convention bad? in case of confusion with other classes or something?

Comment: Because it's bleedingly obvious that they're classes and you're just wasting everyone's time by throwing "C" all around the joint.

Comment: See i had this argument with few others and my tutors, and i was swayed towards using the C convention. I agree with you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no restriction on the number of header or source files for any kind of library.

Comment: When generating the dll, i will need a header to link all this together. So would i have to import the dll into a header then include that into my project in order to use the classes etc. Or could i use __declspec(dllexport) on my overall namespace (seems very hacky to me). And thank you for your answer, means i have not wasted my time.

Comment: import the dll into a header? what?

Comment: My misunderstanding of the import export feature. I know now i must export all the classes. Just sortin gout the header to use with the dll